# How to assign volatile float variable to any other variable?

Tags: c, embedded

I declare one volatile float variable in `file1.h`:

```
volatile float DC_VOLT;                 //AN03
```

and I want to use it in another file like `file2.c` assigning it to a global variable of file2.c:

```
volatile float GEN_VOLT = DC_VOLT;
```

But a compiler error is shown

> error:- initializer element is not constant

and one another interesting thing happened: when I performed the assignment with a local variable of function it worked

```
void CMP_PLL(void)
{
    volatile float GEN_VOLT =DC_VOLT;                      //Here it works
    if(GEN_VOLT>(float)PLL_Range)                         
    {
        if(PLL_VOLT<Vref_PLL)
        {
            CMP_Synch();
            SYNCH_Flag =1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            CMP_Asynch();
            SYNCH_Flag = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CMP_Asynch();
        SYNCH_Flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Can you suggest how to do the assignment with a global variable of a local file?

Comment: To initialize global variables you must use compile-time constants. When `GEN_VOLT` is initialize the the value of `DC_VOLT` will be zero (since it's a global variable).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are mixing assigning a value with intitializing a variable. Initialization value must be constand at build time. Another variable does not qualify for that.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, I want to express What you mean. But I am not good at English..., So I don't know how to express.

Comment: @guapi in that case it's best to just use the wording from the C standard.

Comment: @Gerhardh I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Constant expressions aside, it doesn't make the slightest sense to initialize a global variable to the value of another global variable. Simply activate common sense: which one gets set first? You'd end up with the same irrational static order initialization fiasco as in the C++ language. This is one of the reasons why C doesn't allow it - nobody wants multiple obscure and incredibly complex initialization rules as in C++. It would also make C programs as slow at booting up as C++ ones.

Comment: The code shown in the question suggests `volatile` is not being used correctly. What is your purpose in qualifying `DC_VOLT` and `GEN_VOLT` as volatile? What are these variables supposed to represent?

Comment: @shadab  The initialization of `GEN_VOLT`  in `volatile float GEN_VOLT = DC_VOLT;` deserves protection against `DC_VOLT` partially changing in the middle of the read -rare but possible.  Perhaps something like `interrupt_enable_save(&state); interrupt_disable(); volatile float GEN_VOLT = DC_VOLT; interrupt_set(state);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to initialize a global variable you need the *r_value* of the assignment to be a constant. From [C spec 6.7.9§4](https://www.port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p4):

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

What happens, basically, is that the compiler needs a constant value to initialize the global variable which we be placed in the [proper section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) of the object file.
Please note how the submentioned clause doesn't include local variables, and that's why in your second example things work. When `CMP_PLL( )` function is called, `GEN_VOLT` variable is placed in the stack and initialized with the value that `DC_VOLT` has at the moment the function is called.

---

What you can do, if it makes sense in your application (as `DC_VOLT` volatile variable is probably meant to be updated by some ISR), is to define a common init value used for bot variables:

```
// In file1.h
#define DC_VOLT_INIT 3.3

volatile float DC_VOLT = DC_VOLT_INIT;


// In file2.h
volatile float GEN_VOLT = DC_VOLT_INIT;
```

Otherwise you could directly link `GEN_VOLT` to `DC_VOLT` making it a pointer.